# Assign a subtemplate to specific items in K2

Tags: templates, articles, k2, template-override

I have several items in a category. I'd like to assign  to some of them another template instead of the one inherited from the category template view. I know I could create a new category with new template, but as you could guess I need all the items in the same category.

Is it possible to assign a new template only to specific items in a k2 category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there's no built in way to achieve this, but I've found a very nice etension from the famous NoNumber developper, precisely [Advanced Template Manager](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedtemplatemanager).

If anyone can suggest a native way of doing so please let me know!